# Configuring SSL for an AWS Load Balancer Attached to an Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-application-load-balancer

I currently have a DNS entry for a Load Balancer that only accepts HTTP requests. I already have a domain name from GoDaddy, and currently, the domain is pointing to a single instance IP using a Type A record, with SSL configured on that instance.

Now, I want to switch the domain to point to the Load Balancer which is attached to Auto Scaling group, and I'm uncertain about how to configure SSL for this setup.

I have imported my SSL certificate details into ACM and attached the certificate(issued) to the ALB's HTTPS rule. However, the ACM certificate details do not show significant information. I am planning to switch my domain mapping to the ALB using a CNAME record. My concern is whether SSL will be configured successfully after making this switch. The setup is in production, and I am hesitant to make changes without confirmation.

Note that I am not using Route 53 for DNS management but directly using the GoDaddy dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

To use SSL on ALB, you need to create a listener on the HTTPS port (443) and attach the ACM certificate to it. When you create the ACM certificate, ensure you correctly match the domain (or subdomain) used to connect to ALB. The problem would be if you created an ACM certificate for the domain `example.com` and you used some subdomain like `api.example.com`. If you're using the subdomain, you can create an ACM certificate that supports both domain and wildcard subdomains (`example.com` and `*.example.com`)

For the listener, set the `forward to target group` rule and set the target group to use HTTP port (80), to connect to your instance. If you use 443 here, you would be required to install the certificate on the instance itself, which you are trying to avoid here.

With these things set, once you change your A record to CNAME pointing to ALB, it should all go smoothly.